# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - Angular Post Request to PHP

Tags: php, json, angular, typescript, http-post

I am using angular 2, and I am trying to send data from angular through a post request to a php file on my server. When I try, I get this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". Here is the code I have so far. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

**App component button**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="postData()"> Make Post Request </button>
```

**app component code** I use this function and call it on a button in the template to send the request

```
postData(){
this.requestService.postSomeData()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.postRequest = data,
    error => console.log('There is an error: ' + error),
    () => console.log("Completed Post Request!")
  );
}
```

**Request Service code** -- Here is the service I am calling in the app component

```
postSomeData(){
   let url = 'link to php file here';
   let jsonData = {
       name: 'my Name'
   };
   let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(url, jsonData, {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

PHP File

```
<?php

 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $name = $request->name;
 echo "Name: ".$name;

 ?>
```

Comment: Not sure where you're getting this error, but right above it, put `console.log()`, and echo out whatever data you're trying to decode. You may be getting XML instead of JSON.

Comment: What you need to do is look at whatever data is being sent across with the request. Open developer tools, go to the network tab and trigger the ajax to fire. You can look at the request headers and body. I would just be guessing, but I assume you are sending some extra data like html along with the ajax request. If that looks fine, look at the response information. Perhaps you have some php error being sent back, complete with html.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ok. I sent the request and checked the network tab and it says status 200,  I see the form data as a json object. Is there anything specific I should look for?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? On the client (e.g. console) or from php?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn  Two errors. from client it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" and from php it says "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: well there you go. Make sure that the data you are sending over is valid json. Else json_decode won't work for you. You can dump out the raw sent over information in php with something like `var_dump($postdata )`. Does that look like valid json? If it isn't, then the client side isn't sending json data. You can also `var_dump($request)` to see what that variable has in it. It is obviously not an object which is why you are getting that error. json_decode will return true, false and null if those values are sent over or an object if valid json.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn So I var_dump the request and I get "object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'person' (length=6)", but when I echo it out, it gives me the non-object error.

Comment: Well, I don't know then and can't reproduce it. Here is a copy/paste of the code above with nothing but a manual json array that has the same data structure (assumed based on the var_dump data above): https://3v4l.org/q2dVl. I would suggest just making sure you have spelled everything right, php is case sensitive for things like key names. You could also try using an array instead of an object by passing `true` as the second argument to json_decode. Then access the property like `$request['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the fact that in the PHP (server-side I assume) there is no response returned.